# Как на Android считать бинарный файл в массив (структуру)?

Tags: android, файлы

Имеется файл типа *.model размером 140мб, считывать(по байтово) его нужно для отрисовки в OpenGL ES 2.0.
В структуре файла имеется int32 число, которое обозначает кол-во точек, и координаты x,y,z для каждой точки.

Алгоритм примерно такой:
Первые 4 байта это число Int32, следом за ним идут числа(в байтовом формате) которые мне нужно считать и перевести во float. После считывания по целочисленное число, должно идти новое число состоящие из 4-х байт и это число тоже должно обозначать кол-во точек.
Прикрепил картинку, показывающую структуру файла.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как правильно считать файл?

Использую split, но не могу понять, как правильно задать размер считывания.

```
public class ReadFile {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public float[] read_file() {
        float[] mass_vertices = new float[0];
        String fileName = "city.model";
        Log.w("W", "СЧИТЫВАЕМ ФАЙЛ");
        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName);
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(myFile)) {
            System.out.println("Размер файла: " + fin.available() + " байт");
            int i = -1;
            //задаем размер для буфера
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
            while ((i = fin.read()) != -1) {
                //замутить копирование в файл
                fin.read(buffer, 0, fin.available());
                System.out.print((char) i);

            }
            Log.w("W"," I = " +i);
            Log.w("W","BUFFER = " + buffer.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        Log.e("E", "__________________________________");

        return mass_vertices;
    }
}
```

Comment: Говорят что стандартный, считывается CATIA. Хочу изменить свой вопрос. Мне его нужно по байтово считывать имея структуру на руках. Создать несколько массивов и занести в эти массивы данные.

Comment: @Kromster исправил)

Comment: У вас по сути 2 вопроса - как считать бинарные данные с локальный массив, и как скормить их OpenGL для отображения. Вам неясны оба вопроса иил с каким-то справитесь сами?

Comment: @Kromster со скармливаем OpenGL-у справлюсь, а вот со считыванием файла, проблема, выяснил что первые 4 байта это число int 32, оно и является разделителем, т.е получается что запись в первый массив должно заносится кол-во точек равное числу int 32, как мне занести в массив эти числа? и как получить число из 4-х байт?

Comment: Если к OpenGL вопросов нет, то уберем его из заголовка вопроса. Чем точнее вопрос, тем лучше ;-) Уточнение номер два - проблема в том чтобы прочитать, или в том чтобы узнать точный формат файла?

Comment: @Kromster Проблема в том что бы прочитать, с бинарными файлами не работал практически. Посмотрите вопрос заново, добавил картинку и примерный алгоритм выполнения.

Comment: Я не знаю ответа, но пробую улучшить и конкретизировать ваш вопрос, чтобы те, кто ответ знают, его увидели и поняли.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо большое за отзывчивость=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может у тебя не правильный порядок старшенства байт не вижу команды
ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN это актуально если модель выезжает из под MAXSCRIPT

Answer (score 1):

Вот так сожно читать двоичные файлы 
1)Для получения разрешений я рекомендую использовать внешнее хранилище, такое как SD-карта

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

2)вы можете создать там папку и сохранить свои файлы. Вы также можете использовать «/ data / local /», если ваша система позволяет сохранить файлы пользователя.

3)Чтение файла

```
File file = new File("myFile");
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
dis.readFully(fileData);
dis.close();
```

Comment: Добавил код класса. По которому я считываю файл, обычный файл считывается хорошо, но с бинарным проблема, файл лежит на телефоне, и директорию я тоже задаю.

Comment: File не работает для сторонних файлов на андроид 10+, используйте Uri.